# c# fetch anything that looks like a URL

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to fetch anything that looks like a URL from a string

how would i do this with c#?

most of the are going to look like this: http://www.something.com, but some may look like this: http://something.somethingelse.com

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use RegEx for that. Here's a [handy article](http://weblogs.asp.net/farazshahkhan/archive/2008/08/09/regex-to-find-url-within-text-and-make-them-as-link.aspx) that will get you started. It's an ASP.NET article that wants to find URLs and turn them into hyperlinks but performs the activity you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're parsing some [X]HTML - Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Wikipage).

Straight from the examples page:

```
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];

    //Do stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the context, but you will generally use regular expressions (`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class). To get more specific answers, like code, you will need to provide what the surrounding string might look like so that we know how to differentiate url from non-url.